# Match countries with continents in streamlit selectbox

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have a df where I've used pycountry to get full names for country column and continent column and make select box in streamlit like so,

```
country              continent
Hong Kong              Asia
Montenegro            Europe
Rwanda                Africa
United States      North America
Germany               Europe
Myanmar                Asia
Saudi Arabia           Asia
etc..                  etc..

Streamlit code:

continent_select = df['continent'].drop_duplicates()
country_select = df['country'].drop_duplicates()

continent_sidebar = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select a continent:', continent_select)
country_sidebar = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select a country:', country_select)
```

Desired output: I would like country names for specific continent to show in select box ie: Select 'Asia' from continent select box. Then in country select box, Hong Kong, China, India, etc... show up.

[image: Streamlit Select Box]

I've tried to group the rows into a list with continent

```
df2 = df.groupby('continent')['country'].apply(list)
continent_sidebar = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select a continent:', df2)
```

But this results in having a full list in the select box ie: [Rwanda, Morocco, Sudan, etc.]

Is there an easier way besides making a dictionary and grouping them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the code.

#### Code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'country': ['Hong Kong', 'Montenegro', 'Rwanda', 'Myanmar', 'Saudi Arabia'],
    'continent': ['Asia', 'Europe', 'Africa', 'Asia', 'Asia']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

continent_select = df['continent'].drop_duplicates()
# country_select = df['country'].drop_duplicates()

continent_sidebar = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select a continent:', continent_select)

# Get dataframe where continent is the continent_sidebar.
df1 = df.loc[df.continent == continent_sidebar]

# Get the country column from df1.
df2 = df1.country

# Show df2 in the side bar.
country_sidebar = st.sidebar.selectbox('Select a country:', df2)
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: That worked. I've used loc to pull up a specific value but not all and match with another column. I could use the same procedure to combine another column ie: 'views', right?